# Volume ProgressBar, OffsetX is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've created an audioplayer in javascript/jquery. The desktop version works well, but on mobile phones I'm not able to make the volume progress bar usable.

First I had same problems with play/pause-Button, but that's now fixed.

I found out, that offsetX seems not to work with mobile devices.

I've tried pageX and clientX, but don't fixed this.

I'm an absolute Newbie with javascript, so I hope someone can help.

```
function updateVolumeProgressBar(audio) {
    let volume = audio.volume * 100;
    $(".volumeBar .progress").css("width", volume + "%");
}
this.audio.addEventListener("volumechange", function() {
        updateVolumeProgressBar(this);
    });

$(".volumeBar .progressBar").on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
            mouseDown = true;
          console.log("test4");
        });

        $(".volumeBar .progressBar").on("mousemove", function(e) {
            if(mouseDown === true) {
                let percentage = e.offsetX / $(this).width();
            console.log(e.offsetX);
                if(percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 1) {
                    audioElement.audio.volume = percentage;
                }
            }
        });
$(".volumeBar .progressBar").on("mouseup", function(e) {
            let percentage = e.offsetX / $(this).width();
            if(percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 1) {
                audioElement.audio.volume = percentage;
            }
        });


        $(".volumeBar .progressBar").on("touchend", function(e) {
          var orig = e.originalEvent;
            let percentage = (orig.offsetX) / $(this).width();
          console.log(orig.offsetX);
            if(percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 1) {
                audioElement.audio.volume = percentage;
            }
        });
$(document).mouseup(function() {
            mouseDown = false;
        });

        $(document).on("touchend", function() {
            mouseDown = false;
        });
```

UPDATE: My Javascript changed

```
function initProgressBar(audio) {

    var length = audio.duration;
    var current_time = audio.currentTime;

    // calculate total length of value
    var totalLength = calculateRemainingTime();
    jQuery(".progressTime.remaining").text(totalLength);

    // calculate current value time
    var currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(current_time);
    jQuery(".progressTime.current").text(currentTime);

    var progressbar = document.getElementById('timeSeek');
    progressbar.value = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration);
    $(progressbar).on("vclick", seek);


    function seek(evt) {
        var seekto = audio.duration * (progressbar.value / 100);
        var percent = evt.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
        audio.currentTime = percent * audio.duration;
        progressbar.value = percent / 100;
    }

}



function Audio() {

    this.currentlyPlaying;
    this.audio = document.createElement('audio');

    this.audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        nextSong();
    });


    this.audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
        if(this.duration) {
            initProgressBar(this);
        }
    });

    this.audio.addEventListener("volumechange", function() {
        updateVolumeProgressBar(this);
    });

    this.setTrack = function(track) {
        this.currentlyPlaying = track;
        this.audio.src = track.path;
    };

    this.play = function() {
        this.audio.play();
    };

    this.pause = function() {
        this.audio.pause();
    };

}
```

The HTML-Part

```
<div class="playbackBar">

        <span class="progressTime current">0:00</span>

        <div class="progressBar">
                <div class="progressBarBg">
                        <progress id="timeSeek" value="0" max="1"></progress>
                </div>
        </div>

        <span class="progressTime remaining">0.00</span>


</div>
```

Comment: Why You don't use a slider? Just as an example, see here:  [jQuery Mobile Slider](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/slider/), here: [Styling seek slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841216/styling-seek-slider) or here: [Volume Slider](https://codepen.io/emilcarlsson/pen/PPNLPy)

Comment: @deblocker The problem is in the "seek" function with offsetX. On Desktop it works great. But on a mobiler device, when I tab a position in the progressbar, it skips to the next track. What I need is someone who can help me to change the seek function...

Comment: On mobile, You need to handle a *set* of touch events, see `changedTouches` here: [MDN Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) - conversely, by using a `slider` You will need only to track the `change` event.